# How to use multitenancy with Blazor application in ABP Framework

Tags: abp

I'm trying to create a multi-tenanted blazor application using ABP Framework and i'm struggling to figure out how to implement as the documentation is very limited.

My application needs to resolve the tenant based on the url. A tenant can have multiple urls, so therefore need to create a custom tenant resolver which looks up a url table for the tenant and returns the correct id. I have tried this in the HttpApi.Host project and its working fine but the issue is that it doesnt know anything about the URL that the blazor application was loaded on.

I'm now thinking about adding an http header to the api requests with the url, so that the tenant resolver can pull it. Before i head down this path, i'm concerned there is much easier and better way to accomplish this problem i'm tackling?

Answer (score 0):

> the documentation is very limited.

The documentation is rich, and the code is open source.
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Multi-Tenancy#tenant-resolvers
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.MultiTenancy/Volo/Abp/AspNetCore/MultiTenancy

Answer (score 0):

Since ABP has multiple options to create the front-end application the documentation on multi tenancy in context of Blazor is indeed too limited to accomplish url based multi tenancy.

We are trying create a multiorganization application and we would like to have it url based. We want a single user to be able to access multiple organizations using multiple browser windows so using an url based switch seems like a logic move. This means that we cannot use the tenant id from the user table.

It would be nice if we could use EF core’s global data filters and not need to get the current organization value in every page to pass to the repositories.

The problem with the Blazor system is that the browser url is not part of every interaction with the server and it is needed to create some sort of CurrentOrganizationProvider that works well with Blazor server.

I do agree with Smuggler that the documentation does not provide enough to get this to work within a Blazor server front end.